# centering subcaptions (without text), just keeping (a), (b)..etc

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment, subcaption

How can I write no subcaptions but keeping subcaptions number. That is, how can I just keep (a), (b), (c) ... and, in turn, center those letters below each picture?

Example:

```
\begin{figure}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=centering}
\centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[scale=1]{fig/genero1.png}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:hyper_N5xx_gender_11}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
     %add desired spacing between images, e. g. ~, \quad, \qquad, \hfill etc. 
      %(or a blank line to force the subfigure onto a new line)
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[scale=1]{fig/genero2.png}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:hyper_N612_gender_11}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
     %add desired spacing between images, e. g. ~, \quad, \qquad, \hfill etc. 
    %(or a blank line to force the subfigure onto a new line)
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[scale=1]{fig/genero3.png}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:hyper_N614_gender_11}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[scale=1]{fig/genero4.png}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:hyper_N624_gender_11}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
     %add desired spacing between images, e. g. ~, \quad, \qquad, \hfill etc. 
      %(or a blank line to force the subfigure onto a new line)
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[scale=1]{fig/genero5.png}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:hyper_N7070_gender_11}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
     %add desired spacing between images, e. g. ~, \quad, \qquad, \hfill etc. 
    %(or a blank line to force the subfigure onto a new line)
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[scale=1]{fig/genero6.png}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:hyper_N7071_gender_11}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \caption{Gender distribution of hypertensive individuals per each CRG in 2011}\label{fig:distri_hyper_11} 

\end{figure}
```

Comment: Hm, your code sniped do exactly what you like to have. What is the problem?

Comment: There `\centering` missing in each `subfigure`. Without them the (a) etc. are actually centered, but the images are not.

Comment: @Zarko the point is that (a), (b), (c)... are aligned to the left. I want to center it just below each picture.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt  I added \centering just below the begin{subfigure} command and above the \includegraph... and all of images are unfitted (It is actually a mess).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, seems to be some misunderstanding here. Slightly rearranged of sub figures in figure (grouped in two groups of three sub figures), correct using of `\hfill` (last one in your code is sufficient), gives:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\captionsetup[sub]{justification=centering}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:hyper_N5xx_gender_11}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:hyper_N612_gender_11}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:hyper_N614_gender_11}
    \end{subfigure}
    \bigskip


    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:hyper_N624_gender_11}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:hyper_N7070_gender_11}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.32\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:hyper_N7071_gender_11}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Gender distribution of hypertensive individuals per each CRG in 2011}\label{fig:distri_hyper_11}
\end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

Instead of your images I use example-image, which provide ˙graphics˙package. Of course, I don't know anything about your preamble. Maybe you have there something, which cause your problem ...

**Addendum:** For subcaption set up is correct code `\captionsetup[sub]{justification=centering}˙ (corrected in above MWE). The same result with above MWE you also obtain, if you use`caption` package with for example the following set-up:

```
\usepackage[justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
```

Also, with `\bigskip` after first line of  sub figures, as suggestzed Mico in his commentm you obtain better looking of whole figure. This is now added to MWE.

Comment: I'd add `\bigskip` or `\medskip` immediately ahead of the second group of three subfigures. Separately, is `\captionsetup[sub]{justification=centering}` needed?

Comment: @Mico, good point. I will add it. Setup for subcaption is needed only if caption is setup as `justified` or `raggeright`m both with `singlelinecheck=false`.

Comment: oh I see, I did not have \usepackage[justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false]{caption} in my preamble. Thanks both Zarko and @Mico